# The type UpdateHuntListReq was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm getting the following error when calling code generated from a Cisco WSDL file and was hoping someone could spot where I'm going wrong.

I've had a look round the answers to similar questions on here but I'm obviously still missing something.

"The type UpdateHuntListReq was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

This is where I get the error:

```
    <System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("CUCM:DB ver=8.0 updateHuntList", _
Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, _
ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)> _
        Public Function updateHuntList(<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("updateHuntList", [Namespace]:="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0", [Type]:=GetType(NameAndGUIDRequest))> ByVal updateHuntList1 As UpdateHuntListReq) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("updateHuntListResponse", [Namespace]:="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0")> StandardResponse
            Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("updateHuntList", New Object() {updateHuntList1})
            Return CType(results(0), StandardResponse)
        End Function
```

And this is the top of the UpdateHuntListReq class:

```
 <System.SerializableAttribute(), _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0"), _
XmlInclude(GetType(NameAndGUIDRequest))> _
Partial Public Class UpdateHuntListReq
        Inherits NameAndGUIDRequest

        Private newNameField As String
        Private descriptionField As String
        Private callManagerGroupNameField As XFkType
        Private routeListEnabledField As String
        Private voiceMailUsageField As String
        Private itemsField() As XCommonMembersExtension

    .... Rest of the class
```

Thanks for any help

Mike